# why is my ihttphandler (IIS7 integrared) not being called for some urls

Tags: iis, httphandler

```
<add name="scep" verb="*" path="scep/*" type="xxxxx"/>
```

I get called on a GET to

```
/root/scep/?operation=GetCACert&message=foo
```

and

```
/root/scep/?operation=GetCACaps&message=foo
```

but not

```
/root/scep/?operation=PKIOperation&message=XXXXX(long base64string)
```

I set maxQueryStringLength to allow this long URL but I dont get called. IIS returns 404 to the client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems that there is an upper limit to the length even when max query length set